# Who is God of death - Shiva or Yama?

Tags: shiva, yama

Who is God of death - Yama or Shiva ?

Comment: Yama is the devata of death. Shiva is the Lord of the lord of death. Eg. During the Markandeya episode when Yama came to take Markandeya away, Lord Shiva stopped Yama from doing so.  Shiva is the lord who with his untidy locks of hair dances at the end of time to destroy the universe, while laughing and fire emerging from his eyes. Namah Shivaya

Comment: opinion question. according to different texts, they both are.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - whole of Hinduism is opinions then. It is silly to mark every question as opinion based except what you consider common to all darshans. river - death itself is comprised of 3 - kala, mrityu and yama. kala devata tells it's time for atma to die. mrityu devata physically takes prana out of body e.g. through disease, or accident, or snake bite etc. yama judges whether that atma is good or bad after he dies. Shiva is destroyer of all worlds, he doesn't usually deal with day to day stuff like death.

Comment: @Adiyarkku sir which scripture discusses the Markandeya-Shiva incident? Is it a sthala purana? Could you name it please?

Comment: It's Sam(Bho) with his promotion, So Bow please : - )

Comment: @LSSJBroly Check my answer for details

Comment: @mar sir who is mrityu devata? And by Kala devata do u mean the one who came to Lord Rama to tell him about his departure? Where can I get more info about Kala devata and Mrityu devata?

Comment: @LSSJBroly - 3 devatas combine into what we normally call 'god of death' - kala devata who is like alarm clock (yes, same devata who met Rama secretly and when lakshmana intervened accidentally he was sentenced to death), mrityu devata who is like executioner who takes life out of body using whatever ordained means, then yama who is like judge who determines where the atma is going to after 1 year post death.

Comment: Thannks @ram ji

Answer (score 1):

Shiva is supreme soul Paramatma, he never come into cycle of death or birth, so he is ever pure. ocian of love and ocian of knowledge ( thrimurthi thrikala darshi)
Shiva is not god of death, when shanker become equal to shiva he plays the role of destruction of the dharma of ravan raj
the death hear is death from body consciousness of worldly life but he is the giver of life

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).